# Injecting Activity object in MVP Koin

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, mvp, koin

I am using Koin to inject Activity to the preseneter, but existing instance of Activity isn't passed to the presenter. New one is created instead. What am I missing?

```
val mainModule = module {
    single<IStartupActivity> { StartupActivity() }
    factory<IStartupPresenter> { StartupPresenter(get()) }
}

class StartupPresenter(val view: IStartupActivity): IStartupPresenter {
}

class StartupActivity : Activity(), IStartupActivity {
    val presenter: IStartupPresenter by inject()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}

I/KOIN: +-- 'inf.ecg.presenter.interfaces.IStartupPresenter' 
D/KOIN: |-- [Factory     [name='IStartupPresenter',class='inf.ecg.presenter.interfaces.IStartupPresenter']]
I/KOIN: |   +-- 'inf.ecg.view.interfaces.IStartupActivity' 
D/KOIN: |   |-- [Single [name='IStartupActivity',class='inf.ecg.view.interfaces.IStartupActivity']]
D/KOIN: |   |-- inf.ecg.view.implementations.StartupActivity@4176160
I/KOIN: |   \-- (*) Created
D/KOIN: |   !-- [inf.ecg.view.interfaces.IStartupActivity] resolved in 4.378594 ms
D/KOIN: |-- inf.ecg.presenter.implementations.StartupPresenter@ddfe619
I/KOIN: \-- (*) Created
D/KOIN: !-- [inf.ecg.presenter.interfaces.IStartupPresenter] resolved in 18.235835 ms
```

Comment: The Android system creates Activity classes, not you.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question has been asked a while ago, but here's the solution for those who end up here.

This can be solved by declaring the activity as a param to your injection like this:

```
val myModule = module {
    single<IStartupPresenter> { (view: IStartupActivity) ->  StartupPresenter(view) }
}
```

then in inject it to your activity:

```
class StartupActivity : Activity(), IStartupActivity {
    val presenter: IStartupPresenter by inject { parametersOf(this) }

...
}
```

Koin documentation about [injecting parameters](https://doc.insert-koin.io/#/koin-core/injection-parameters).

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @EpicPandaForce, the Android system creates Activity classes, and you can not just create/inject it.

If want to access your activity's interface from presenter, you could use a variable to set it.
In `IStartupPresenter` you could write:

`val activity = IStartupActivity?`

And in `StartupActivity` you add:

```
class StartupActivity : Activity(), IStartupActivity {
    val presenter: IStartupPresenter by inject()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        presenter.activity = this
    }
}
```